# How to rollback a specific record after a test?

Tags: testing, groovy, spock

I have a spock / spring test which modifies some database content, and I wonder how to rollback that record.

Currently I execute a raw sql statement, save the field data and after successful test I restore that data. But my guess is that this can be done in an easier way?

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath*:applicationContext-test.xml")
class RepositoryTest extends Specification {

    @Shared sql = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:sqlserver://...")
    ResourceRepository resourceRepository;

    def "Save test"() {
        setup:
        // copy the row before we do changes! we need to restore this later on!
        def row = sql.firstRow("select id, content, status from table-name where id = 12345")

        when:
        ...

        then:
        ..

        cleanup:
        sql.execute("""
                    update table-name set content = ${row.content}, status = ${row.status}
                    where id = ${row.id}
                    """)
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you really want to rollback a specific record, rather than whatever the test method did?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I've found to do this is:

- start test
- start transaction
- (optional) load any DB data the test requires using something like DBUnit
- run test
- rollback transaction

Notice that all DB operations occur within the same transaction. Because this transaction is rolled back at the end of the test (even if an exception is thrown), the database should always be in the same state at the end of the test as it was at the start.

Spring provides some really useful classes that will take care of starting and rolling back the transaction for each test. If you're using Spring & JUnit4 and don't mind that your test classes have to extend a Spring class the easiest option is probably to extend `AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests`

```
// Location of the Spring config file(s)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"/application-context-test.xml", "classpath*:/application-context-persistence-test.xml"})

// Transaction manager bean name
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "hsqlTransactionManager", defaultRollback = true)
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public class MyTransactionalTests extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests {

    @Test
    public void thisWillRunInATransactionThatIsAutomaticallyRolledBack() {}
}
```

If you don't want to extend a Spring class, you can configure a test-runner instead using annotations. Spring also supports many of the other major unit-testing frameworks and older versions of JUnit.

Comment: Because Spock has direct support for Spring's TestContext framework, you neither need a base class nor a custom runner. @TransactionConfiguration can be omitted in favor of naming the bean "transactionManager". To make Groovy's Sql class work with Spring's transactions, you'll have to initialize it with a Spring-provided data source. The fact that the Sql class doesn't perform exception translation a la Spring may affect in what cases transactions are rolled back.

Answer (score 1):

If you're mixing Groovy's Sql with Spring's Annotations (@RunWith, @ContextConfiguration, @Transactional, @Rollback, ...) on your tests, you may want to wrap the dataSource with a org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy.

```
<bean id="db-dataSourceReal" 
   class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
  <property name="jndiName" value="jdbc/foo" />
  <property name="resourceRef" value="true" />
  <property name="lookupOnStartup" value="true" />
</bean>

<bean id="db-dataSource"
   class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy">
  <constructor-arg ref="db-dataSourceReal" />
</bean>
```

Then use the TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy as the dataSource for your Groovy Sql. For example, in your Test class (in this case using maven's failsafe plugin),

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations=[
        "classpath*:applicationContext-test.xml"
])
class SimplePojoDaoIT {

    @Resource(name="dao-pojoDao")
    PojoDao pojoDao

    @Test
    @Transactional("transactionManager")
    @Rollback
    public void testShouldPersistToDB(){

      SomePojo pojo = new SomePojo()
      pojo.with{
        id = 5
        name = 'foo'
      }

      pojoDao.persist(pojo)

      def sql = new Sql(pojoDao.dataSource)
      sql.rows("select * from POJO_TBL where id = :id", [['id':pojo.id]]).each{ row ->
//      println row
        pojo.with{
          assertEquals(id, row.ID.longValue())
          assertEquals(name, row.NAME)
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE table_name
(
   id        NUMBER,
   content   NUMBER,
   status    NUMBER
);

INSERT INTO table_name
     VALUES (1, 2, 3);

INSERT INTO table_name
     VALUES (4, 5, 6);

INSERT INTO table_name
     VALUES (7, 8, 9);

COMMIT;
```

Before running the test, you store the string resulting from this SELECT in a VARCHAR2(4000) variable, and after the test you have only to execute the string:

```
SELECT    'UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET CONTENT = '
       || CONTENT
       || ', STATUS = '
       || STATUS
       || ' WHERE ID = '
       || ID
  FROM TABLE_NAME
 WHERE ID = 1;
```

In my previous example I have supposed that the record to backup has ID = 1.
The string, in this example, contains the following UPDATE statement:

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET CONTENT = 2, STATUS = 3 WHERE ID = 1
```